# Issue configuring AngularJS SPA template with Web Api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, single-page-application, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to use VS 2013's AngularJS SPA template with Web Api, but application never enters my controller even thou it goes into app.js section that calls that controller, here is my setup:

WebApiConfig.cs inside App_Start folder

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
//using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace App.TheForm
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

FormController.cs inside Controllers folder:

```
namespace App.TheForm.Controllers
{
    public class FormController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> GetFormList()
        {
            List<DataRow> formList = new List<DataRow>();
            SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MyConnection;Initial Catalog=Forms;Integrated Security=True");

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Get_FormList", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter pFormId = new SqlParameter("@FormId", 3);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(pFormId);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
                itList<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return rows;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Close();
            }

            return null;
        }            
    }
}
```

AngularJS controller:

```
app.controller('FormController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('api/form/getformlist').success(function (data) {
        $scope.formlList = data;
    }).error(function () {
        alert('Error reading JSON file.');
    });

    }
});
```

index.cshtml

```
@{
    PageData["title"] = "AngularJS SPA Template for Visual Studio";
}
<h2>Welcome!</h2>
<p>This is just a demo page.</p>

<table ng-app="app" border="1" ng-controller="FormController">
    <tr ng-repeat="form in formlList" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
        <td>
            {{form[0]}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{form[1]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

RouteConfig.cs inside App_Start:

```
namespace App.TheForm
{
    using System.Web.Routing;

    using App.TheForm.Routing;

    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.Add("Default", new DefaultRoute());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I only have this problem when using AngularJS SPA Template. When I recreate this project using Empty Web Application with Web Api, everything works just fine. I think AngularJS SPA Template messes up configuration and routing of the project.

Comment: can you post the HTML that is involved?

Comment: just posted it at the bottom of my question

Comment: your Route Template in the WebAPI looks strange.... `api/{controller}/{id}` wouldn't match up with the route you have, `api/{controller}/{action}`

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend using Attribute Routing in WebAPI2.  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: did change it to `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional }`, but no change

Comment: does `http://yourserver.com/api/form/getformlist` show raw data if you browse to it in your browser?

Comment: no, as I said earlier it doesn't get inside `getformlist` code, I also noticed since I use AngularJS SPA Template it created RouteConfig.cs inside App_Start may be it causes this issue, I have added its code to the end of my question. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71837/discussion-between-claies-and-superconsultant).

Comment: I have changed it to a chat.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$http.get('api/form')` instead of `$http.get('api/form/getformlist')` at cliend side.

Comment: zhimin, thanks for your help. I have tried it but result is the same. Especially when there are multiple GET methods. I think the problem is somewhere in configuration, as application doesn't seem to be aware of the location of "api/form".

Answer (score 0):

I would change this to:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/form")]
public class FormController : ApiController
{
    [Route("getFormList")]
    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> GetFormList()
```

and then I believe your call should succeed.

Comment: Unfortunately not, as I mentioned in UPDATE section at the top, it seems like AngularJS SPA Template causes the problem.

Comment: Which template is this? Can you post a link to it?

Comment: I get that template when chose to create new project under Templates->Visual C#->Web in Visual Studio Premium 2013. It is call AngularJS SPA Template.

Comment: I assume you have an addin that provides that because I don't have that template in mine.

Comment: Maybe I downloaded it a while ago from online templates section.

Comment: you would have to let me know which add-in you have. it is hard to tell whats wrong without it

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Also, what does the call look like from your browsers network tab?

Comment: peinearydevelopment thanks for your help but at this point I just switched back to using WebApi project and manually creating SPA and it works great.